# Reverse first k elements of a list

Tags: list, haskell

I'd like to reverse the first k elements of a list efficiently.

**This is what I came up with:**

```
reverseFirst :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
reverseFirst 0 xs rev     = rev ++ xs
reverseFirst k (x:xs) rev = reverseFirst (k-1) xs (x:rev)

reversed = reverseFirst 3 [1..5] mempty -- Result: [3,2,1,4,5]
```

It is fairly nice, but the `(++)` bothers me. Or should I maybe consider using another data structure? I want to do this many million times with short lists.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. I guess the real question is: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to solve the [fannkuch-redux problem](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/fannkuchredux-description.html#fannkuchredux). The current solution is slow and ugly.

Comment: Right. So it's a benchmark to see how quickly you can swap stuff, rather than produce an actual useful result...

Comment: If you are doing this for a benchmark against other languages which use arrays instead of linked lists, I would use arrays instead of linked lists. Otherwise, the comparison is quite unfair, IMHO.

Comment: The current solution does use arrays.  I'm not sure why you consider it "slow and ugly," though...or why you think linked lists would outperform arrays.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, well, it *is* a lot slower than the leading implementations. This may be due in part to it being sequential rather than parallel. The heavy use of unsafe vector operations could be seen as ugly, and the code could really use some comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's think about the usual structure of `reverse`:

```
reverse = rev [] where
  rev acc [] = acc
  rev acc (x : xs) = rev (x : acc) xs
```

It starts with the empty list and tacks on elements from the front of the argument list till it's done. We want to do something similar, except we want to tack the elements onto the front of the portion of the list that we don't reverse. How can we do that when we don't *have* that un-reversed portion yet?

The simplest way I can think of to avoid traversing the front of the list twice is to use laziness:

```
reverseFirst :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
reverseFirst k xs = dis where
  (dis, dat) = rf dat k xs

  rf acc 0 ys = (acc, ys)
  rf acc n [] = (acc, [])
  rf acc n (y : ys) = rf (y : acc) (n - 1) ys
```

`dat` represents the portion of the list that is left alone. We calculate it in the same helper function `rf` that does the reversing, but we also *pass it* to `rf` in the initial call. It's never actually examined in `rf`, so everything just works. Looking at the generated core (using `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dno-suppress-type-signatures`) suggests that the pairs are compiled away into unlifted pairs and the `Int`s are unboxed, so everything should probably be quite efficient.

---

Profiling suggests that this implementation is about 1.3 times as fast as the difference list one, and allocates about 65% as much memory.

Answer (score 2):

Well, usually I'd just write `splitAt 3 >>> first reverse >>> uncurry(++)` to achieve the goal.

If you're anxious about performance, you can consider a difference list:

```
reverseFirstN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
reverseFirstN = go id
 where go rev 0 xs = rev xs
       go rev k (x:xs) = go ((x:).rev) (k-1) xs
```

but frankly I wouldn't expect this to be a lot faster: you need to traverse the first *n* elements either way. Actual performance will depend a lot on what the compiler is able to fuse away.

Comment: If I read the STG correctly (big if), you're building a closure for each of the reversed elements, at least on GHC 7.8.3.